# OpenQuery from SQL Server to Oracle server hangs indefinitely if connection is lost

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I have a scheduled job which runs on a SQL Server 2005 database. It runs a stored proc which imports data from a View. This View consists of an `OPENQUERY` to a linked Oracle server.

I have no control over the Oracle server - it is both geographically and virtually separated from the Sql Server installation. The View just has read-only access and I grab the data from it every 30 mins.

On occasion, the connection to the linked server will either drop, hang or be otherwise unresponsive. When this happens, the Job (on SQL Server) also hangs, waiting indefinitely for the connection to return. The Job never fails nor completes in this scenario and the first I know about it is when users complain about missing data.

Querying a database on the *same server* fails as expected if there's a connection problem - it's only when `OPENQUERY` is used on the linked Oracle server that it loses its 'awareness' of the connection.

Is there a way to make the job realise the connection to the Linked Server has dropped and fail accordingly? Or do I have to create a second Job to check that the first one hasn't hung?

Comment: is this maybe a serverfault.com question?

Answer (score 0):

We were having similar issues for long running operations. The op would be started (and also did his work and finished), but the call never returned. Eventually we were able to trace this down to a firewall closing the connection to the Oracle server.

We could prevent this by using the parameter SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME on the server, which would periodically "ping" a client and thus keep the firewall from closing the port. Maybe this helps in your case as well.

Comment: You're right, this does sound like it would solve the problem! Unfortunately, this also sounds like an Oracle setting (am I right?), which means we have no powers to modify it (it's geographically in a different country, different legal entity etc. etc.). If there was something similar for SQL Server to make it keep 'talking' to Oracle, then we might be in business!