# What are the drawbacks of using linked servers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Are there any huge performance issues or security concerns?

Using SQL Server 2005 and higher

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Server migrations are more convoluted
- Security can be tricky to set up for multi-hop
- Non-SQL Server ones requires a local driver installed (Sybase, DB2 etc)
- Clusters, off-site DR: registry entries + drivers
- Non-SQL Server x64 woes. 'Nuff said
- Non-SQL Server ones don't play well (how many places to enter the password?)
- Performance (in other answers)

I've set up linked servers to Access, DB2, Oracle, Sybase and the odd proprietary ODBC driver. I'd prefer SSIS or .net code now...

Answer (score 9):

Yes - Queries which join two datasets in different physical databases perform poorly.

e.g. If you run a query between table A on the current server and B on a linked server.

```
 Select A.Field1, B.Field2 FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.Id = B.Id
 WHERE B.Id = @InputId
```

you may find that all the records for table B are retrieved - effectively

```
 Select * from Table B
```

into the working server.

What you'd want to do instead is have a usp on the linked server which takes an Id as a parameter and returns a filtered recordset from Table B

Then rewrite the query above to join Table A to the usp instead.

Comment: Thank you for this very useful bit of information and workaround.

Comment: @BonyT- Sorry but what is usp , didn't get the same ?

Comment: @userx - User Defined Stored procedure.

Answer (score 5):

Having one (or many) set up on the server isn't the issue - the performance hit will be when you come to actually query them.

I have a Linked SQLServer 2005 set up, which is in the same physical building (on the same network) and it's not a problem - fast as you like.

I also have another Linked (Oracle) server which is on the other side of the world that is like walking through treacle and times out, drops connections (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637689/openquery-from-sql-server-to-oracle-server-hangs-indefinitely-if-connection-is-lo)!)

Sorry to be vague, but ...it depends!